# Сортировка массивов по алфавиту

Tags: php

Как можно вывести список имен и фамилий по алфавиту? Иванов, Петров, Сидоров, к примеру, и т.д.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sort($massive, SORT_STRING);
```

Или просто

```
sort($massive);
```

Если нужно сортировать ключи массива, то:

```
ksort($massive);
```

Comment: + если тупит с русскими, нужно установить локаль через `setlocale` и юзать `SORT_LOCALE_STRING`

Comment: Почему то выводит цифрами, а не текстом?

Comment: попробуйте var_dump($massive);<br>
Что выведет?

Comment: Скорее всего, 

>     Замечание: Эта функция присваивает новые ключи элементам массива. Она удалит все существующие ключи, а не просто переупорядочит их.

Comment: Ааа, вы сортируете ключи) Тогда Вам подойдёт функция ksort